# How to add application-specific icons to current theme?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, icons, freedesktop.org

I'm writing a GUI application using Python and Qt. In this application I want to "decorate" dialogs and output data with theme icons like `document-open` or `dialog-error`. This is easily retrieved with a statement like:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
…
… = QIcon.fromTheme("dialog-error")
```

The exact icon to retrieve is designated by an index into a list, which results in the following code:

```py
DECORATION = [ None, "dialog-error", "document-open", "app-specific" ]
…
     … = QIcon.fromTheme(DECORATION[i])
```

I'd like "app-specific" to point to some user directory acting like an addition to the current theme, in order to manage theme- and user-icons in the same statement.

Presently, I have given this user-directory the same structure as */usr/share/* with *icons/* and *applications/* subdirectories. In *icons/*, there is a *hicolor/* directory containing the "size" subdirs and *actions/* with my additional icons.

I already added in the application main window initialisation:

```py
    def __init__(self):
      …
        searchPath = QIcon.themeSearchPaths()
        searchPath.insert(0, XDG_DIR)
        QIcon.setThemeSearchPaths(searchPath)
      …
```

where `XDG_DIR` is a string containing the absolute path to my *icons/* directory.

This doesn't work. I correctly retrieve the "standard" freedesktop.org icons but not mine.

- is the patch valid only in the widget where it is done (and its descendants) and not effective in "independent" widgets like an error dialog?
- should my patch on `themeSearchPaths` be done **before** initialising the application (and Qt)?
- should I provide a *xxx.theme* configuration file? If so, how do I tell the library I only want to add a few icons (not intending to copy everything from a real theme)?

I don't want to create a system-wide theme. I only want the patch to be effective during application execution so that other applications are not polluted.

Comment: It seems you didn't call [`setThemeName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#setThemeName).

Comment: I don't call `SetThemeName()` because user should be free to choose any desktop theme. I forgot to mention I'd like to retrieve the app-specific icons independent of theme (at least at this stage). I tried `setFallbackSearchPathe()` without success. If I add some "fallback theme", have I to configure an *index.theme* in full, which I try to avoid because I only aim at adding a small handful of icons?

Comment: Qt always uses the default system theme, `setThemeSearchPaths` only sets the search path for the *themes*, not the icons. If you want to use icons from *another* theme with `fromTheme()` you must specify *that* theme. The fallback mechanism will eventually use the default whenever your theme doesn't provide an icon.

Comment: @ajlittoz You could easily write a function that uses `QIcon.hasThemeIcon()` to check if an icon should be loaded from elsewhere (e.g. via the resource system). The function could go in a utils module so it can be imported wherever it's needed. That would be much simpler to maintain than trying to augment the system theme itself.

Comment: @ekhumoro's suggestion is a promising track. How can I know which size Qt would have chosen among the possibilities? If I return an "icon" from *scalable/* (SVG images), have I to also return a preferred size so that my custom icons remain size-consistent with the theme ones?

Comment: @ajlittoz The whole purpose of [QIcon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html) is to avoid needing such knowledge. In the minimal case, you simply supply a single image, and Qt works out all the rest. Of course, if you want specialised images for particular combinations of size/mode/state (e.g. to avoid scaling issues), you must explicitly add them as well. But really, this is just a somewhat crude, short-term solution. The correct approach is to install your application-specific icon files in the hicolor theme, which is the default fallback for all themes.

Comment: @ajlittoz PS: I would urge you to fully familiarise yourself with the [Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) if you really want to understand how things work (especially the parts related to the hicolor theme). You might also want to look at the [xdg-icon-resource](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-icon-resource.html) tool, which is part of [xdg-utils](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/).

Comment: I have implemented @ekhumoro's idea and it is way simpler than trying to tweak the theme engine. Thanks a lot.